# Customize notify_url in rest api

Tags: paypal

From the sample code by Paypal:

http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html

How can I define a notify_url in this practice like express checkout?

I found there's a method `setNotifyUrl` in PayPal\Api\TransactionBase Class, but it seems doesnot work correctly

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into Webhooks?  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/

Comment: I don't have a ssl cert to set up webhooks!

Comment: I get IPN based on the profile setting still when using REST, that could be a workaround for you?

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer doesn't seem to apply anymore; it appears that, although this is undocumented, `notify_url` *is* used by the PayPal REST API. The following code works fine:

```
actions.payment.create({
            payment: {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: 100,
                            currency: "USD" },
                        notify_url: "http://www.example.com"
                    }
                ]
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

As oppose to the Classic APIs, PayPal REST APIs does not support `notify_url` "on-the-go" in the payload parameters, which means you would still rely on the pre-configed IPN url in your PayPal account as a central listener.

(though the parameter "`notify_url`" is left Read-only and reserved for future use)

*WebHooks will be the first option for REST API call-backs management, an SSL URL is mandatory though.*

If there's a need of dynamic IPNs for REST API (use case like multiple e-commerce sites with single PayPal account), the recommendation as of now is to turn your central IPN script into an "dispatcher", so that the Call-Back message goes to the designated listener based on the condition block of the "dispatcher" script.